# If I install Lubuntu desktop will I still be able to use Gnome Shell and Unity?

Tags: 11.10, gnome, lubuntu

If I install Lubuntu-Desktop (or Xubuntu-Desktop, for that matter) from the Software Centre, in Ubuntu 11.10, will I still be able to use Gnome-Shell and Unity, or will those be deleted? Will it be added on to the little cog at the login screen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Installing the LXDE Meta Package (its a 13Mb download) from Software Center does add a few new sessions:

[image]

[image]

Choosing LXDE:

[image]

and yes - Gnome Shell and Unity still work...

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you! All the other guides only said how to install it, not how to activate it.